# How to inject string properties containing < character into Spring beans?

Tags: java, spring

I have following bean definition for my DAO -

```
<bean id="userDao" class="UserDao">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="queryPurgeInvalidReferrals" value="delete from reference where date < ?" />
</bean>
```

I am getting the error - 
The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "property" must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: escape the value &lt; to work as it is in XML document.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since Spring config is an XML file, you need to escape `<` according to XML syntax:

```
<property name="queryPurgeInvalidReferrals" 
    value="delete from reference where date &lt; ?" />
```

Answer (score 13):

Try with this:

```
<property name="queryPurgeInvalidReferrals">
    <value><![CDATA[delete from reference where date < ?]]></value>
</property>
```

Comment: I don't think it works. Since value is an attribute, could you define as element inside property.Though I didn't look at Spring XSD or DTD.

Comment: The Spring XSD allowed me to do that. But I haven't tried to read the value element. Here's all that can go into a `<property>` element:  `(description?, (meta | bean | ref | idref | value | null | array | list | set | map | props | 
 namespace:uri="##other")?)`.

Comment: The `property` tag can take value is either an attribute or as a child-element. For string values, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use unicode like

```
<property name="queryPurgeInvalidReferrals" value="delete from reference where date &#x3c; ?" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in your value string **<** must be replaced  by `&lt;`

```
value="delete from reference where date < ?"
```