# The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "property" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: spring, spring-batch

```
<bean id="fileDiffTaskelt" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.SystemCommandTasklet" scope="step">
<property name="command" value="diff #{jobParameters['INPUT_FILE']} #{jobParameters['PREVIOUS_FILE']} |  grep -e '<' -e '>' | grep -x '.\{20\}' > #{jobParameters['FILTERED_FILE']}"/>
<property name="timeout" value="60000"/>
<property name="workingDirectory" value="/tmp/hub"/>
</bean>
```

I'm getting this error in my IDE : The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "property" must not contain the '<' character. Im using this character in my grep command and is very essential, stuck here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject string properties containing < character into Spring beans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171183/how-to-inject-string-properties-containing-character-into-spring-beans)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Escape Strings` for the same.

Replace `'<'` in value attribute as `&apos;&lt;&apos;` .

```
    <property name="command" value="diff #{jobParameters['INPUT_FILE']}
      #{jobParameters['PREVIOUS_FILE']} |  grep -e &apos;&lt;&apos; -e &apos;&gt;&apos; 
      | grep -x '.\{20\}' > #{jobParameters['FILTERED_FILE']}"/>
```

Similarly use for appropriate `escape strings` for `'>'`

[XML Escape Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222367/escape-quote-character-in-xml)

Answer (score 1):

You can use special characters.

```
< &lt;
> &gt;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/bc4j/developing_bc_projects/obcCustomXml.htm